# How to update values in a Service's own variable?

Tags: angularjs

I have a basic data Service, which will be used for multiple Controllers. In the Service, I have some predefined fields which I will get via $http.

I am currently having trouble updating that variable after getting the $http response - I keep getting the error `dropdownData is not defined`. I know it's probably something very basic, so please let me know.

Service:

```
angular.module('core').service('FormService', ['$http', function($http) {

    this.dropdownData = {
        contactTimes: ['Anytime','Morning','Afternoon','Evening'],
        industries: {},
    };

    $http.get('/json').success(function(resp){
        dropdownData.industries = resp.industries; 
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining this in a variable:

```
  angular.module('core').service('FormService', ['$http', function($http) {
var $this = this;
$this.dropdownData = {
    contactTimes: ['Anytime','Morning','Afternoon','Evening'],
    industries: {},
};

     $http.get('/json').success(function(resp){
    $this.dropdownData.industries = resp.industries; 
});
```

}]);

*this* is redefined depending on the function call context. By storing *this* in a variable, you can reuse it in your closure.

Answer (score 0):

Capture a reference to `this` and use it in the callback...

```
angular.module('core').service('FormService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var service = this;
    this.dropdownData = {
        contactTimes: ['Anytime','Morning','Afternoon','Evening'],
        industries: {},
    };

    $http.get('/json').success(function(resp){
        service.dropdownData.industries = resp.industries; 
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe use var can solve your problem

```
var dropdownData = {
    contactTimes: ['Anytime','Morning','Afternoon','Evening'],
    industries: {},
};
```